# How to make hanging lists using memoir?

Tags: lists, margins, indentation, memoir

I found the `\hangsecnum` command for having section numbers hanging out into the left margin. Now I want to do the same thing for all lists also, that is for the `enumerate` and `itemize` environments at least and maybe also for `description` if it is possible. I have been searching but not come up with any obvious ways of doing this.

Just to be clear here is some ASCII-art showing what I want to do:

```
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
   Donec accumsan, quam eget mollis eleifend, elit libero 
   molestie quam, vitae gravida eros lorem eget diam. 
   Nulla mollis cursus condimentum. Luctus eget vestibulum:

 * ante 
 * ipsum 
 * primis 

   On faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia 
   Curae; Donec consequat elementum dictum. Suspendisse metus
   turpis, venenatis at mollis quis, porta sit amet lectus:

 1 aliquam 
 2 erat 
 3 volutpat

   Vestibulum posuere convallis nibh a lacinia.
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following up on daleif's suggestion, here's a way to implement this with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum} % package used only for blind text
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0em]
\item Libert\'e
\item Equalit\'e
\item Fraternit\'e
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

If you want to make that change global, add this to your preamble:

```
\setitemize{leftmargin=0em}
\setenumerate{leftmargin=0em}
\setdescription{leftmargin=0em}
```

Or for all three at once:

```
\setlist{leftmargin=0em}
```

You might want to treat descriptions differently, though. I've not tested it...

Comment: There are also commands to set enumerate and descriptions: `\setenumerate` and `\setdescription`.

Comment: @N.N. Yes. I should mention those, I guess.

Answer (score 5):

`memoir` does not provide any interfaces for lists, try the `enumitem` package, it is really easy to do with that package